# REST API Design: Should we use same endpoint with diff params or create a new endpoint

Tags: java, rest

I am working on designing Rest API. I have a existing end point say

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/games", params = {"tId", "sId"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

which search games . Now I need to search games based on different set of attributes. I have two options:

a) Use same endpoint "/games" but takes different set of input params like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/games", params = {"tId", "day"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

2) I should create a seperate endpoint(URL) for this.

Kindly Advice.
Also if I go with second option, what should be the endpoint name should be.

Comment: Are these two REST calls doing and/or returning the same thing?

Comment: Yes, both return the same domain object. Only diff is the input param types. First one takes int,int and second one takes int,Date.

Answer (score 3):

Given that both intended endpoints/endpoint return the same thing, I might opt for keeping a single REST endpoint which accepts *all* possible parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/games", params = {"tId", "sId", "day"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

You can add logic to the handler method which checks to see which incoming parameters have been defined, and based on that choose the appropriate course of action.  You may need to add logic which detects if someone is misuing the REST endpoint and return an error in that case (e.g. by defining both `sId` and `day`).

Comment: I have a bit complex case where the existing API is taking (int , int ,int , String,List,List,int)  .  I need to support search on addtional 3 params . Should I add support in the  exisitng endpoint ..?

Comment: Yes, but was this case described in your question?